# null exception on a for each control var

Tags: vb.net

i'm getting a null pointer exception on (tvn.Tag) in this block:

```
For Each tvn In SelNode.Nodes
    If tvn.Tag = "Ports" Then tvn.Remove()
Next
```

how's this possible?
full sub:

```
Private Sub btnScan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnScan.Click
        MGlobals.OpenPorts.Clear()
        Dim SelNode As TreeNode = TreeView1.SelectedNode
        Dim tvn As TreeNode

        For Each tvn In SelNode.Nodes
            If tvn.Tag = "Ports" Then tvn.Remove()
        Next
        tvn = SelNode.Nodes.Add("Portas Abertas")
        tvn.Tag = "Ports"

        tvn.Nodes.Add(tvn.Parent.Text)

        TreeView1.Select()
        TreeView1.SelectedNode = SelNode
    End Sub
```

Comment: By nothing being assigned to `Tag`. What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: `For Each tvn As TreeNode In SelNode.Nodes If tvn.Tag?.ToString() = "Ports" Then tvn.Remove() Next`. Set `Option Strict On`.

Comment: that tvn is nothing

Comment: same error @Jimi. thank you.

Comment: `TreeView1.SelectedNode` is null (`Nothing`)? You need to debug your code. Null checks are quite important, always verify if an object is null before accessing it.

Comment: no @Jimi. I debugged. That's why I'm here.

Comment: I don't see any null-check in that code, so it appears no real debugging has been made, yet.

Comment: maybe I'm not understanding your point @Jimi but in visual studio do you need null-checks in code? seeing the value of vars on the debugger isn't reliable?

Comment: Visual Studio is a development environment. It has nothing to do with the code. You could write your code in Notepad.  When you will compile/link your code and produce an executable, unhandled exceptions will make your app crash and die.

Answer (score 3):

Typically if you tried to remove an item from a collection while enumerating said collection, a collection modified exception would be thrown.  However, the `TreeNodeCollection` class and the enumerator it uses does not implement such logic.  When a node is removed, the backing array is compressed by copying higher index nodes to fill the removed node.  If the array was initially oversized this means the position of the highest index position is now null.  Due to the enumerator setting the total number of nodes at its creation, it sadly acts as a for-next loop and can eventually return null values.

The solution is the same as for when removing items from other collections,  use a decrementing For-Next loop.

```
For i As Int32 = SelNodes.GetNodeCount(False) - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim tvn As TreeNode = SelNodes.Nodes.Item(i)
    If tvn.Tag IsNot Nothing AndAlso tvn.Tag.ToString = "Ports" Then
        tvn.Remove()
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

the Tag property is type object and you check the object for Nothing before casting or calling .ToString If you know it is a string then you also have to cast it out as such.

```
    If tvn.Tag IsNot Nothing Then
        If CType(tvn.Tag, String) = "Ports" Then tvn.Remove()
    End If
```

Comment: thank you. didn't really tried it because prior solution worked but yours makes sense to me